# Crawling a javascript variable inside HTML file with web-harvest

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, webharvest

I have a question (dummy maybe). Suppose that I have the following snippet of code inside an html page with a bunch of other things (other script tags and html tags):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    var active = false;
    var mapData = **{"points":   [{"type":"origin","name":"6003","lnglat":"174.77851504231018,-41.278763329010459,0\n"}]}**;
</script>
```

And I would like to scrape only the content of mapData variable (which is in bold in the example above).

I am struggling with the xpath expression that I need to use in my xml configuration file to get only the mapData variable content. As I am new with XPath/Web-harvest, I am not sure if the solution is using xpath expression or maybe other approach.

All the other times I have based my scraping on HTML tags and the name of the id attributes inside it, but now I only have a lot of script tags inside the file and I need to get the mapData variable.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It is an object, what xpath are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use where ${SiteURL} is your website URL to hit:

```
<xpath expression="for $m in $x//script[contains(text(),'var mapData')] return normalize-space(substring-after($m,'var mapData ='))">
        <html-to-xml>
          <http url="${SiteURL}"/>
        </html-to-xml>
      </xpath>
```